# jquery getting checked radio value in ie8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

```
var un = $('input[name=tur]:checked').val();
alert(un);
if (!un) {
    isValid = false;
    $('#msg_username').html('Error.').show();
} else {
    $('#msg_username').html('').hide();
}
```

I tried alert(un) for control; ie doesn't take value of radio group with `$('input[name=tur]:checked').val();`. It comes undefined in ie.
No problem in firefox.

How can i get value of checked radio button for ie?

Comment: I think you meant to use `||` (or) instead of `&&` (and). Why would you test `un.length` when `un` is `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `NaN`, `0`, or `''`? It only makes sense to test it when `un` is a string. And even then, `!un` is `true` for an empty string, so the `.length` test is unnecessary.

Comment: Felix has the solution, but if you do test the length, try `.length === 0` - it's not ever going to be less than zero, so `<=` doesn't make sense.

Comment: That was there because it was textbox control and need to be converted to radio group control. Fixed rule, now can i get my answer, why doesn't this working in ie8?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[name=tur]').filter(':checked').val()
```

Also, `if(!un && un.length <= 0)` might be making problems here. Just try `if (un && un !== '')`

Comment: Tried. Still gives `undefined`.

Comment: then try $('input[name=tur]:is('checked')).val();

Comment: @milesh: *"Syntax error in that"* I'm sure you are able to set the correct quotation marks yourself, aren't you?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var un = $("input[name='tur']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no problem in your code, except that you can change your condition

I think you should check whether the `radio button` is `checked` or `not`
By using,

```
var un = $('input[name=tur]').is(':checked');    
// returns true if checked, otherwise false
```

Full code,

```
var un = $('input[name=tur]').is(':checked');
if (!un) {
    isValid = false;
    $('#msg_username').html('Error.').show();
} else {
    $('#msg_username').html('').hide();
}
```

Comment: @milesh test the above answer I've made changes in it.

Comment: Firefox returning true without problem, but ie8 is returning false. Checked control is not working too.

Comment: Which `version` of `jquery` you are using? I tested it in `IE8` with `jQuery 1.9.1` and its **working**.